# Change background on hover with CSS3 rounded corners

Tags: html, css

I have a table and one side of the table is an array of links.  Currently I have a background color change on hover to make it appear as if the cell in the table has been pressed.  The problem with this is, after setting the `display:block` property on the cells, when the cell is hovered over it leaves out the rounded edges and looks bad.  Any way to deal with this?

CSS

```
.bigtable {

    text-align:left;
    padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;
    color:white;
    border: 2px solid #999999;
    margin:0px 5px 0px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius:20px;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px;
    border-radius:20px;
    text-shadow:0 1px 1px white;
    font-size:x-large;
}
td {
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background-color:#0063dc;
    -moz-border-radius:20px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    text-shadow:0 1px 1px black;


}
td a:hover {
    display:block;  
    background-color:blue;

}
```

snippet of table:

```
<table style="width: 100%; height: 730px;" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" class="bigtable">
                    <tr>
                                    <td>news</td>
                                    <td><ahref="">click on this box to read about what is 
                                    mmunity</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
```

i know what the problem is, but i don't know how to fix it.  it's the td a:hover part of the CSS that's doing it what i'm telling it to.  how can i instruct the hover of a link to change the ENTIRE td color, not just the link part?

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet? Your question is a little bit vague. It may be helpful to know that the default display value for td's is 'table-cell,' to the best of my knowledge

Comment: let me know if having the css and html will help.

Comment: sure, i'll edit the original statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the spec, this is how `border-radius` in CSS3 works. The content inside the box with the radius "bleeds" through the rounded corner.

You'll have to give your links a `border-radius` as well.

Comment: ahh. gotcha.  thanks for the tip.  i'll accept when it lets me.

Comment: actually, this still isn't changing the whole td background color, it's just changing the part that's a link.  even though i set display:block.  anyone know the deal?

Comment: added display:block to the td {} part of the css.  it now works like i want, but the table is displayed all screwy.

Comment: @dzilla: Can you create a fiddle, and show us exactly what you're doing? I started one for you: http://jsfiddle.net/RBqW4/ . Modify it, click on the `update` button, and post the link here...

Comment: td a:hover {
    display:block;  
    background-color:blue;
} that part of the code works, but it doesn't change the entire color of the cell, only the part that the link consists off, which is just the text.  i'd like for the entire cell to change color.  and for the record, i added the class 'rightcells' in the html and it still didn't work.

Comment: @dzilla: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to accomplish. Is it something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/RBqW4/4/ ?

Comment: ah, i didn't think about having the hover element for the element.  how silly.  thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try re-applying the CSS for the :hover rule? Else the inline-block may be of assistance.

What browsers display this behavior?

Comment: It seems it's standard complient behavior. May I suggest using overflow:hidden as an alternative to the bleeding effect.

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix for modern browsers would be to apply `overflow:hidden` to the container with the border-radius:

```
td {
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background-color:#0063dc;
    -moz-border-radius:20px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    text-shadow:0 1px 1px black;
    overflow: hidden; /* important bit */
}
```

This should clip the corners of your link and maintain the cell's rounded edges.

Now, if you still wanted to affect the cell from the link, you're going to have to use javascript. CSS, by design, is devoid of parent selectors.

Comment: gives me the same behavior.  should i go at it in javascript?